# Memory occupation increase

Tags: c++, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am trapped in a wired situation; my `c++` code keeps consuming more memory (reaching around `70G`), until the whole process got killed.

I am invoking a `C++` code from `Python`, which implements the `Longest common subsequence length` algorithm.

The `C++` code is shown below:

```
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

#include <stdio.h>

int LCSLength(long unsigned X[], long unsigned Y[], int m, int n)
{

  int** L = new int*[m+1];
  for(int i = 0; i < m+1; ++i)
    L[i] = new int[n+1];

  printf("i am hre\n");

  int i, j;
  for(i=0; i<=m; i++)
  {
    printf("i am hre1\n");
    for(j=0; j<=n; j++)
    {
        if(i==0 || j==0)
            L[i][j] = 0;
        else if(X[i-1]==Y[j-1])
            L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1]+1;
        else
            L[i][j] = MAX(L[i-1][j],L[i][j-1]);
    }
  }
  int tt = L[m][n];

  printf("i am hre2\n");

  for (i = 0; i < m+1; i++)
    delete [] L[i];

  delete [] L;

  return tt;
}
```

And my `Python` code is like this:

```
from ctypes import cdll
import ctypes
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./liblcs.so')

la = 36840
lb = 833841
a = (ctypes.c_ulong * la)()
b = (ctypes.c_ulong * lb)()

for i in range(la):
    a[i] = 1
for i in range(lb):
    b[i] = 1

print "test"
lib._Z9LCSLengthPmS_ii(a, b, la, lb)
```

IMHO, in the `C++` code, after the `new` operation which could allocate a large amount of memory on the heap, **there would be not more additional memory consumption inside the `loop`.**

However, to my surprise, I observed that the used memory keeps increasing during the `loop`. (I am using `top` on `Linux`, and it keeps print `i am her1` before the process got killed)

It is really confused me at this point, as I guess after the memory allocation, there are only some arithmetic operations inside the `loop`, why does the code take more memory?

Am I clear enough? Could anyone give me some help on this issue? Thank you!

Comment: C and C++ are different languages!

Comment: `4 * (36840+1) * (833841+1) * 4 = 122878292488` It is natural to consume more than 70G memory if `int` takes 4 bytes. It will consume about 114GiB.

Comment: I heard that `malloc()` only reserve memory and using the buffer will actually consume memory. The same thing may happen to `new`.

Comment: @MikeCAT You should write that up, it's the correct answer.

Comment: @Harry I won't write it as answer because I'm not sure. You can write it if you want.

Comment: Off topic: You can save yourself a bunch of memory management and probably cache misses by making your array `int* L = new int[(m+1)*(n+1)];` and doing the 2D mapping by hand (`L[i*nPlusOne+j]`)

Comment: @MikeCAT: That completely depends on you system and possibly the specific code if optimistic allocation is used. Relying on this is poor design.

Comment: @MikeCAT I see what you mean now.

Comment: @user4581301: Not sure, but is there no way in C++ to allocate a true 2D array?

Comment: Sidenote: In C and C++, array indexes start from `0` and loops typically use `i < length`, not `<=`. This pattern allows compilers to better optimize code and also makes your code better readable (e.g. you just allocate `n` entries, not `n +  1`) and less error-prone. Not following these conventions increases the risk of errors and missunderstanding by other programmers.

Comment: The reason you are confused is because you are using the word "memory", which can refer to many different things. If you mean physical memory or RAM, say "physical memory" or "RAM". If you mean virtual memory or address space, say "vm" or "address space". When you say "used memory keeps increasing", we can't tell whether you think the program is using more RAM, using more address space, or what. And likely that's how you're confusing yourself.

Comment: "IMHO, in the C++ code, after the new operation which could allocate a large amount of *memory* on the heap, there would be not more additional* *memory* consumption inside the loop." Correct, if by "memory" you mean *virtual memory*.

"However, to my surprise, I observed that the used *memory* keeps increasing during the loop." Correct, if by "memory" you mean *physical memory*.

Be specific so we can tell what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what you are doing:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  int m = 36840;
  int n = 833841;
  unsigned long total = 0;

  total += (sizeof(int) * (m+1));

  for(int i = 0; i < m+1; ++i){
    total += (sizeof(int) * (n+1));
  }

  std::cout << total << '\n';

}
```

You're simply consuming too much memory.
If the size of your `int` is 4 bytes, you are allocating 122 GB.

Answer (score 2):

Your consuming too much memory. The reason why the system does not die on allocation is because Linux allows you to allocate more memory than you can use

```
http://serverfault.com/questions/141988/avoid-linux-out-of-memory-application-teardown
```

I just did the same thing on a test machine. I was able to get past the uses of new and start the loop, only when the system decided that I was eating too much of the available RAM did it kill me.

This is what I got. A lovely OOM message in dmesg.

```
[287602.898843] Out of memory: Kill process 7476 (a.out) score 792 or sacrifice child
[287602.899900] Killed process 7476 (a.out) total-vm:2885212kB, anon-rss:907032kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

On Linux you would see something like this in your kernel logs or as the output from dmesg...

```
[287585.306678] Out of memory: Kill process 7469 (a.out) score 787 or sacrifice child
[287585.307759] Killed process 7469 (a.out) total-vm:2885208kB, anon-rss:906912kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[287602.754624] a.out invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24201ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[287602.755843] a.out cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[287602.756482] CPU: 0 PID: 7476 Comm: a.out Not tainted 4.5.0-x86_64-linode65 #2
[287602.757592] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.8.2-0-g33fbe13 by qemu-project.org 04/01/2014
[287602.759461]  0000000000000000 ffff88003d845780 ffffffff815abd27 0000000000000000
[287602.760689]  0000000000000282 ffff88003a377c58 ffffffff811d0e82 ffff8800397f8270
[287602.761915]  0000000000f7d192 000105902804d798 ffffffff81046a71 ffff88003d845780
[287602.763192] Call Trace:
[287602.763532]  [<ffffffff815abd27>] ? dump_stack+0x63/0x84
[287602.774614]  [<ffffffff811d0e82>] ? dump_header+0x59/0x1ed
[287602.775454]  [<ffffffff81046a71>] ? kvm_clock_read+0x1b/0x1d
[287602.776322]  [<ffffffff8112b046>] ? ktime_get+0x49/0x91
[287602.777127]  [<ffffffff81156c83>] ? delayacct_end+0x3b/0x60
[287602.777970]  [<ffffffff81187c11>] ? oom_kill_process+0xc0/0x367
[287602.778866]  [<ffffffff811882c5>] ? out_of_memory+0x3bf/0x406
[287602.779755]  [<ffffffff8118c646>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8fc/0xa6b
[287602.780756]  [<ffffffff811c095d>] ? alloc_pages_current+0xbc/0xe0
[287602.781686]  [<ffffffff81186c1d>] ? filemap_fault+0x2d3/0x48b
[287602.782561]  [<ffffffff8128adea>] ? ext4_filemap_fault+0x37/0x51
[287602.783511]  [<ffffffff811a9d56>] ? __do_fault+0x68/0xb1
[287602.784310]  [<ffffffff811adcaa>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x6a4/0xd1b
[287602.785216]  [<ffffffff810496cd>] ? __do_page_fault+0x33d/0x398
[287602.786124]  [<ffffffff819c6ab8>] ? async_page_fault+0x28/0x30
```